# From Base64 to Object and vice versa

Tags: javascript, decode, encode

I want to encrypt a *Javascript* object to *Base64* but using a key to decrypt it. This is possible, right?

I tried this but it's for strings only and don't uses a key:

```js
function utf8_to_b64(str) {
  return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
}

function b64_to_utf8(str) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(str)));
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer:

```js
const json = JSON;

function object_to_base64(data, key)
{
    if(data === "object")
    {
        var object_secure = {data: data, key: key};
        
        var object_json = json.stringify(data_secure);

        return btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(object_json));
    }
}

function base64_to_object(data, key)
{
    if(data === "string")
    {
        var object_secure = decodeURIComponent(escape(atob(data)));

        var object_json = json.parse(object_secure);

        var object_data = object_json.data;

        var object_key = object_json.key;

        if(key == object_key)
        {
            return object_data
        }
    }
}
```